# How to display a 64 bit number in decimal in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, overflow, emulation, x86-16, divide

I'm working on an assignment and I'm stuck on divide overflow.
It's giving an error because I'm dividing a 64 bit number `DX AX` by a 32 bit number. The answer doesn't fit in `AX` so it gives an error.

Is there any way to overcome this overflow ? I want to convert this number into decimal so I'm trying to divide it by 10.

Comment: You can implement a division algorithm or use repeated subtraction of powers of 10.

Comment: `ax`  and `dx` are 16-bit registers. Two of them can only form a 32-bit pseudo-register, not a 64-bit one. You need `eax:edx`, which is only available from the **80386** onwards.

Comment: EOF's reply is why comments needs the downvoting-functionality. It's not very helpful and doesn't seem to understand the question. Obviously you can do arithmetic operations on numbers that are too large for the registers available - as seen in the correct answers below.

Answer (score 4):

### Displaying the 64-bit number in `DI:SI:CX:BX` on [8086](/questions/tagged/8086)

#### Step 1. Calculating the digits

This requires using a chain of divisions starting at the Most Significant Word of the 64-bit number. The remainder of every division is re-used on the next division.

```
  mov  bp, 10  ;Constant divider 10
  push bp      ;Will signal the end of the PUSHed remainders
Next:
  xor  dx, dx
  xchg ax, di  ;Most Significant Word is in DI
  div  bp      ;Divide Word3
  xchg di, ax
  xchg ax, si
  div  bp      ;Divide Word2
  xchg si, ax
  xchg ax, cx
  div  bp      ;Divide Word1
  xchg cx, ax
  xchg ax, bx  ;Least Significant Word is in BX
  div  bp      ;Divide Word0
  mov  bx, ax

  push dx      ;Every remainder is [0,9]

  or   ax, cx  ;OR all quotients together
  or   ax, si
  or   ax, di
  jnz  Next    ;Repeat while 64-bit number not zero
```

Please note that the `xchg` instruction was used to reduce code size!

#### Step 2. Displaying the digits

To display the characters I'll presume this is running on DOS.
Should be real easy to adapt this to another OS...

```
  pop  dx      ;This is digit for sure
More:
  add  dl, '0' ;Convert from remainder [0,9] to character ["0","9"]
  mov  ah, 02h
  int  21h     ;DisplayCharacter
  pop  dx
  cmp  dx, bp  ;Repeat until it was the 'signal (bp=10)' that was POPed
  jb   More
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with edx = 0, and eax = upper bits of the dividend. Divide by 10, and eax will be the upper dividend for the next loop so save it. edx will have the remainder, which is used for the next divide: eax = lower bits of the dividend. Divide by 10, and eax will be the lower dividend for the next loop so save it. edx will be the remainder of the 64 bit dividend divided by 10, which will be the least significant decimal digit of the number. Repeat the loop to get the digits in reverse order.

In response to the comment below, assume the 64 bit number is in EDI:ESI (high:low):

```
        mov     ecx,10
loop0:  xor     edx,edx         ;divide high order by 10
        mov     eax,edi
        div     ecx
        mov     edi,eax
        mov     eax,esi         ;divide low  order by 10
        div     ecx
        mov     esi,eax
;                               ;at this point edx contains one decimal digit
;       ...                     ;store the digit and continue with the loop
```

Comment: i cant start with dx = 0. My  number is a 64 bit number DX-AX. i WANT TO DEVIDE IT BY 10 please reply :/

Comment: I updated the answer to show the code. You can write the rest of the code to convert the digits to an ascii string in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

Got the inspiration from rcgldr

here is how it would be done in 8086 since all registers in 8086 are all 16bit

```
                                ;here we have a 64bit number in si:di:cx:bx
loop0:  xor dx,dx
        mov ax,si               ;divide highes order by 10
        div diver
        mov si,ax
        mov ax,di               ;divide high order by 10
        div diver
        mov di,ax
        mov ax,cx               ;divide low oreder by 10
        div diver
        mov cx,ax
        mov ax,bx               ;divide lowest order by 10
        div diver
        mov bx,ax
                                ;right now we have the wanted number in dx
        mov temp,si             ;keep value of si for later
        mov si,[bp+4]           ;make si point to wanted string
        add si,18               ;move to end of string
        sub si,counter          ;move back the amount of times used
        add dx,'0'
        mov byte ptr [si],dl
        inc counter
        mov si,temp             ;put back saved value in si and go again
        cmp si,0
        jne loop0
        cmp di,0
        jne loop0
        cmp cx,0
        jne loop0
        cmp dx,0
        jne loop0
        mov counter,0           ;reset counter
```

I was trying to solve a similar problem for 2 days!! until I read rcgldr's answer. THANK YOU! the only difference was that I needed to divide a 64bit number by 10 in 386 environment and not 8086 but its all the same
and since your question helped me i wrote this code for you in 8086.

Hope it helps someone...

Comment: I think it might be better to describe the 64-bit value from MSB to LSB: `si:di:cx:bx` instead of `bx:cx:di:si`

Comment: Interesting.I would love to know why? What would be the difference?

Comment: I'm not suggesting a change to the code(just the comment), but most often when you have a multipart value across multiple registers you list them from most significant to least significant. It keeps it consistent to what Intel does. For example on x86 `dx:ax`, `edx:eax`, `rdx:rax` use a similar notation where most significant part is listed first and least significant appears last, and each separated by a colon. When I saw the comment in your code I automatically assumed that is was MSB to LSB until I noticed the code goes the other direction.

Comment: Ya but these registers just hold the 64bit number. I could use veriables if i wanted and it would still work the same, i think. Im just a student (who is about to take a final on this cource in 90 min) wish me luck ;)

Comment: The loop will exit too early since it does not check the whole 64-bit number for becoming zero!

Comment: Storing backward into a buffer is good, but it would be simpler to just decrement a pointer instead of incrementing a counter and doing a bunch of pointer math in the loop.  Like `mov si, [bp+4]` / `dec si` / `mov [si], dl` / `mov [bp+4], si`.  When you're done, `[bp+4]` (and maybe `si` depending on when you reload) points to the first byte of the string.

Comment: Also, instead of `temp` static storage, you can stash the original `si` in `ax` which you're not using in that part of the loop.  (You could even hoist the `mov ax, si` out of the top of the loop, and have later iterations just jump up to the `xor dx,dx` with the high 16 of the dividend already in SI.)  You could maybe also optimize the zero-checking to jump to further along in the loop, so once the dividend becomes 48 bit you're only doing 3 divisions per iteration, and so on.  I think that works if your existing chain of test/jnz just jumps later and later into the existing loop.